# Using pandas groupby to group by a conditional across rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the a **pandas** dataframe with the following data:

```
date          random      score 
2022-01-01    4324        0.12
2022-01-02    234         0.46   
2022-01-03    3456        0.51
2022-01-04    12          0.52
2022-01-05    346         0.41
2022-01-06    12          0.42
2022-01-07    4356        0.50
2022-01-08    235         0.20
2022-01-09    23          0.51
2022-01-10    23          0.60
2022-01-11    456         0.45
```

and I am trying to `groupby` (or maybe this is a "filter" instead of a group) the rows whose `score > 0.5`, yet, only keeping the first record matching `score > 0.5` for each "group."

This is best explained by looking at the expected outcome. So in the above example the resulting filtered/grouped rows would be

```
date          random      score 
2022-01-03    3456        0.51
2022-01-07    4356        0.50
2022-01-09    23          0.51
```

**Is it possible to select the first record in a group, where to grouping is defined by a multirow conditional?** I believe I could do this with a loop, but I'm trying to find a more streamlined way.

Comment: Could you explain why there is date `2022-01-07` whose score is not greater than 0.5?

Answer (score 0):

I think `first()` could work:

```py
df[df['score']>0.5].groupby('date').first()
```

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of the `first()` call. Thank you! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Hi @Brett if it works please give me a upvote, as new one to the community I need more reputation to unlock functions :D many thx :D